# value from Observable within Observable using angularfire2 firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to query a sub-collection if exists while querying for `document` from `collection`. My first query `returns/maps` data properly but when I try to query the `subcollection` it will be stored as `observable` within the `Observable<data>`. Below is what I have/tried so far.

**component.ts**

```
availableCategoriesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category>;
availableCategories$: Observable<CategoryId[]>;
lstCategories: Observable<any>;

this.availableCategoriesCollection = this.httpDataService.getAllCategories();
this.availableCategories$ = this.availableCategoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(data => {
  return data.map(record => {
    const rec = record.payload.doc.data() as Category;
    const cId = record.payload.doc.id;
    return {cId, ...rec};
  });
});

this.lstCategories = this.availableCategories$.map(data => {
  return data.map((rec: CategoryId) => {
    //if a category has subcategory then query the document again for subcollection
    if (rec.hasSubCat) {
      return this.httpDataService.getSubCategory(rec.cId).snapshotChanges().concatMap(d => {
        return d.map(r => {
          const arr: any = {};
          arr.id = r.payload.doc.id;
          arr.itemName = (r.payload.doc.data() as Category).categoryName;
          arr.category = rec.categoryName;
          return arr;
        });
      });
    }else {
      const arr: any = {};
      arr.id = rec.id;
      arr.itemName = rec.categoryName;
      arr.category = 'All';
      return arr;
    }
  });
});
```

When I look into the `lstCategories` value, the documents that have `subcollection` will be returned as `Observable` and the ones which don't have `subcollection` returns proper `data` with `id`,`itemName` and `category`. Something like below:

> (9) [{…}, Observable, Observable, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, Observable]

How can I properly subscribe to the `sub-query`? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your problem is that the `map`s callback sometimes returns a plain object and sometimes returns an Observable. I guess you still want to emit an array of objects (including those inside the inner Observables) instead of emitting items one by one.

I think the easiest way to do this is using `forkJoin` and always returning an Observable (even when the result could be a plain object):

```
this.lstCategories = this.availableCategories$.mergeMap(data => {
  const observables = data.map((rec: CategoryId) => {
    if (rec.hasSubCat) {
      return this.httpDataService... // Observable
    } else {
      const arr: any = {};
      ...
      return Observable.of(arr); // Observable
    }
  }

  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
});
```

Also notice that I had to use `this.availableCategories$.mergeMap()` because `mergeMap` will subscribe to the `forkJoin` Observable and emit its result.

Comment: I get **observable_1.Observable.of is not a function** error in console for the statement `return Observable.of(arr);` under `else`. :(

Comment: Ok, I got that issue right, since I was importing `Observable` from `rxjs/observable` wherein I had to import from `rxjs/Observable`. Now the issue is the data will not get displayed when I have `async` pipe in my view. If I `subscribe` to `lstCategories` in component, it never gets invoked. Any idea why is it so?

Comment: This returns data as - `(9) [ScalarObservable, Observable, Observable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, Observable]` i.e. 3 `Observables` and remaining 6 `ScalarObservable`. But this data is not `subscribable` and doesn't work with `async`..