# RxJS Observables does not display data on subscribe or async

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs, angular5, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get all the data from `firestore` -  `collection` and `subcollection` into an `observable` form of `array` and display it with `async` pipe.

```
availableCategoriesCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category>;
availableCategories$: Observable<CategoryId[]>;
lstCategories: Observable<any>;

this.availableCategoriesCollection = this.httpDataService.getAllCategories();
this.availableCategories$ = this.availableCategoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(data => {
  return data.map(record => {
    const rec = record.payload.doc.data() as Category;
    const cId = record.payload.doc.id;
    return {cId, ...rec};
  });
});
this.lstCategories = this.availableCategories$.mergeMap(data => {
  const observables = data.map((rec: CategoryId) => {
    if (rec.hasSubCat) {
      return this.httpDataService.getSubCategory(rec.cId).snapshotChanges().map(d => {
        return d.map(r => {
          const arr: any = {};
          arr.id = r.payload.doc.id;
          arr.itemName = (r.payload.doc.data() as Category).categoryName;
          arr.category = rec.categoryName;
          return Observable.of(arr);
        });
      });
    }else {
      const arr: any = {};
      arr.id = rec.id;
      arr.itemName = rec.categoryName;
      arr.category = 'All';
      return Observable.of(arr);
    }
  });
  return Observable.forkJoin(observables);
});
```

and I've used `<pre>{{lstCategories | async | json}}</pre>` to display the data, but it is always null.

When I `console.log(observables)` before `forkJoin` I get `(9) [ScalarObservable, Observable, Observable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, ScalarObservable, Observable]` out of which 3 of them which are `Observable` are subcategories and 6 of them which are `ScalarObservable` are main categories.

In spite of this data, the lstCategories doesn't get updated via `async`.

I've also tried to subscribe to `lstCategories` like

```
this.lstCategories.subscribe(data => {
     console.log(data);
});
```

but the above log never happens which means it is not getting subscribed. My knowledge on `rxjs` is very weak. Hope to find some help here.

Comment: This is too long and too complicated. Reduce the question / code to the actual part that "breaks". It would also greatly improve your good to break it into several testable functions

Comment: @Amit. Sorry but, that was the only part that was causing issue. I've removed every unnecessary code from there and showed what I am trying to achieve and what I've so far. If I cut down any more then the question will be unclear. :(

Comment: It is indeed a long question but can you change the return line of code block `arr.category = rec.categoryName;
          return Observable.of(arr);` to `return arr;`

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I've tried that but that will break the library which expects `Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`..  :(

Comment: Are you trying to achieve anything like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47174075/firestore-how-to-get-the-collection-value-from-another-collection-document-id-is?answertab=votes#tab-top)?

Comment: @Hareesh - **The firebase/firestore master - _I've an eye on you_ :P** - Absolutely. But with slight modifications according to my needs. I've upvoted your answer. Could you please add it here so that I can edit the same accordingly? :)

Comment: Not a master yet :), just a beginner. And only heard about Rxjs after working with Angularfire library. I will come up with an answer what i understood from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
this.lstCategories = this.availableCategoriesCollection.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Category;
        if(data.hasSubCat){
          const signupId = a.payload.doc.id;
          return this.httpDataService.getSubCategory(signupId).snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
            return actions.map(d => {
              return d;
            });
          }).map(signup => {
            return signup.map(md => {
              const arr: any = {};
              arr.id = md.payload.doc.id;
              arr.itemName = (md.payload.doc.data() as Category).categoryName;
              arr.category = data.categoryName;
              return arr;
            });
          });
        }else {
          const arr: any = {};
          arr.id = a.payload.doc.id;
          arr.itemName = data.categoryName;
          arr.category = 'All';
          return Observable.of(arr);
        }
      });
    }).flatMap(records => Observable.combineLatest(records)).map(data => {
      return [].concat(...data).map(d => {
        return d;
      })
    });
```

Comment: Buddy.. I have finally got this working version. If you have any suggestions on the end result/code please let me know.. :) Thanks for your help..

Comment: I am glad my suggestion helped. can you explain this `[].concat(...data).map`?

Comment: The **[answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49407067/rxjs-move-array-of-objects-to-root-array/49408017#49408017)** explains pretty much about that. I was intending to move subcollection items to the main root object. and hence had to do with concat and spread syntax as per suggestion.. :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are returning `Observable` of `Observable` of some array at following code block

```
map(d => 
...
arr.id = r.payload.doc.id;
arr.itemName = (r.payload.doc.data() as Category).categoryName;
arr.category = rec.categoryName;
return Observable.of(arr);
...
```

This block is already inside a map function of an Observable. When you return another Observable your whole return object looks like `Observable<Observable<any[]>>`
Just change return line to `return arr;`

Comment: Yea.. Tried it, But still it doesn't get anything when I `subscribe` or `async`..

Comment: Also, why do you use `mergeMap`? If it is not for a particular reason, can you change it `flatMap`?

Comment: Well that was for one of the answers **[received here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49391733/value-from-observable-within-observable-using-angularfire2-firestore)**

Comment: Here is the difference between them. https://tolikcode.github.io/post/rxjsMap/ if you want to wait for all the values you should use `flatMap`. I know RxJs is really confusing at first. Also, I'm still trying to understand where is the problem.

Comment: But as mentioned in the post `flatMap` is just an alias for `mergeMap` right? and also I tried with `flatMap`. Still it is not getting values. The one doubt am having is why is it not getting `subscribed` or working with `async`?

Comment: Did you change the inner part? That has to be changed for sure. Because, when `rec` `hasSubCat` you are returning `Observable` of `Observable`s. Otherwise, just a single `Observable`. Keep that return line as I shown in my answer and continue from there.

Comment: Yes. I did that too. Now I am having `flatMap` instead of `mergeMap` and just returning `arr` inside `if` as you said.

Comment: Also, can you try to subscribe both to `lstCategories` and `Observable.forkJoin(observables)` and console log the content?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167226/discussion-between-guruprasad-rao-and-bunyamin-coskuner).

Comment: Buddy.. Thank you so much for all the help today. Really appreciate it. I have solved the problem. Please see below accepted answer. :)

Comment: @GuruprasadRao You are welcome. I'm glad you solved it. The problem was with `forkJoin` after all huh :). But seriously though, you should try to simplify that code for the future. It's quite complex.

Comment: I agree with your point of simplifying the current code. I am open for suggestions though.. ;) Will have code clean up work in future.. :) But honestly,  this is the least I could think of so far..

Answer (score 0):

When you use map, you transform the response of a request. You needn't return an Observalbe

```
this.httpDataService.getSubCategory(rec.cId).snapshotChanges().map(d => {
        return d.map(r => {
          const arr: any = {};
          arr.id = r.payload.doc.id;
          arr.itemName = (r.payload.doc.data() as Category).categoryName;
          arr.category = rec.categoryName;
          return arr  //<--simply return arr
          // return Observable.of(arr); <--I think it's WORNG
        });
```